# bash for loop doesnt print correctly

Tags: bash

I have this simple for loop

```
#!/bin/bash
for number in {1..10}   
    do
        echo $number
    done
```

but when I execute it with sh test.sh the output is

```
{1..10}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare at the top that the script uses bash and run it with sh.

If you just type this in the command line it will work:

```
./name_of_the_script
```

Alternatively, you can call on the bash interpreter explicitly:

```
bash name_of_the_script
```

Comment: What is the way to execute it with sh?,Thank you.

Comment: Use correct sh syntax: 

`for i in $(seq 1 10); do
        echo $i
done`